# How can I adjust this ggplot code to alter the name of the legend/key?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have tried multiple solutions I found online but I think the issue is specific to the way I've written this code:

```
ggplot(Polarity_Subjectivity2, aes(x = Subjectivity, y = polabs)) + geom_point(aes(colour = factor(Stars))) + ylab("Polarity")
```

The legend is produced as "factor(Stars)" but I just want "Stars" and the few things I've tried have not managed to change the name. I've tried the following:

```
+ guides(fill=guide_legend(title="New Legend Title"))
```

```
+ scale_fill_discrete(name = "New Legend Title")
```

```
+ labs(fill='NEW LEGEND TITLE')
```

Comment: You mapped to `colour`, not `fill`, so try any of your solutions using `colour` instead. :)

Comment: The aesthetic is “colour” but all of your labeling attempts reference “fill”.